# Separation of the repository by content (separation of parsing and data processing)

Tags: github

The goal of the project is to create a recommender system in which I go through all the stages of building, training a model from collecting and processing data, creating a model to implementing it into a bot.
The problem is that I don't know if it's worth splitting the repository into two, one is responsible for collecting information, and the second for building a model. The resulting model will be used in the telegram bot, so this part of the project must also be placed in the same repository or create a separate one that will copy the model (one file) from their repository.

The first option is not to separate the repository and store parsing, processing and model building in separate folders, but this option is not always convenient, the second option is to create two separate repositories, but then the project building logic will collapse, that is, data collection, this is a strange part of the project, that it is in a separate repository. Does the community have certain rules in such a situation?